# How to detect if variable has redirect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

## React Router Dom V6

I have two loader functions which send request to server

```js
async function loadUserDetail(userId, userAction) {
  const token = getAuthToken();
  const userResponse = await axios({
    url: API.endpoint + '/user/user-detail/' + userId,
    params: {},
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: token,
    },
    validateStatus: () => true,
  });
  return responseHandler(userResponse);
}

async function getAllPermissions() {
  const token = getAuthToken();
  const permissionsResponse = await axios({
    url: API.endpoint + '/permission/permission-dropdown',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: token,
    },
    validateStatus: () => true,
  });
  return responseHandler(permissionsResponse);
}
```

I have a response handler from which I am managing all loader and action responses.

Response Handler

```js
export function responseHandler(response) {
  if (response?.data?.success === false) {
    toast.error(response.data.message, {
      position: toast.POSITION.TOP_RIGHT,
    });
    return null;
  }
  if (response?.data?.success === true) {
    toast.success(response.data.message, {
      position: toast.POSITION.TOP_RIGHT,
    });
    return response.data.data;
  }
  if (response.status === 401) {
    localStorage.clear();
    toast.error(response.data.message, {
      position: toast.POSITION.TOP_RIGHT,
    });
    // <Navigate to="/" />
    return redirect('/');
  }
  toast.error('Something went wrong', {
    position: toast.POSITION.TOP_RIGHT,
  });
  return redirect('/');
}
```

And finally I have a loader

```js
export async function loader({ request, params }) {
  const { userId, userAction } = params;
  const responseToSend = {
    permissions: await getAllPermissions(),
    userDetail: await loadUserDetail(userId, userAction),
    userAction,
  };
  return responseToSend;
}
```

Now the problem is that when response handler returns redirect then loader is returning a object by assigning redirect object as a property of either **permissions** or **userDetail** instead of redirecting.

Now in component function

```js
const { userDetail, userAction, permissions } = useLoaderData();
```

My Question is: After extracting `userDetail` and `permissions` how can I detect if any one of them contains redirect object and if contains then just redirect it to where I have redirected from response handler?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest returning an object with either a `data` or `redirect` property. These would be trivial to check. If either of `permissions` or `userDetail` has a truthy `redirect` value, return a redirect, otherwise return the object with the packed `permissions`, `userDetail`, and `userAction` properties.

Example:

```js
const toastOptions = {
  position: toast.POSITION.TOP_RIGHT,
}

export function responseHandler(response) {
  if (response.data?.success === false) {
    toast.error(response.data.message, toastOptions);
    return { data: null };
  } else if (response.data?.success === true) {
    toast.success(response.data.message, toastOptions);
    return { data: response.data.data };
  }

  if (response.status === 401) {
    localStorage.clear();
    toast.error(response.data.message, toastOptions);
  } else {
    toast.error('Something went wrong', toastOptions);
  }

  return { redirect: '/' };
}
```

```js
export async function loader({ params }) {
  const { userId, userAction } = params;

  const permissions = await getAllPermissions();
  const userDetail = await loadUserDetail(userId, userAction);

  if (permissions.redirect) {
    return redirect(permissions.redirect);
  }

  if (userDetail.redirect) {
    return redirect(userDetail.redirect);
  }

  return {
    permissions: permissions.data,
    userDetail: userDetail.data,
    userAction,
  };
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much brother for answering as well as letting me know how can I improve my code. I appreciate your efforts and time. Thank You again.